# Object disappears when trying to simulate Soft Body physics

Tags: baking, soft-body

I  am trying to get my object to fall into the glass jar and bounce about. However, on the 20th baked frame my object disappears until the end of the simulation. I've taken a look at the dimensions of my object and it sky-rockets on the 20th frame, but I don't know why. And yes, all the vertices of the object are connected.

- 1st Image : Frame 1
- 2nd Image : Frame 19
- 3rd Image : Frame 20

[image]

[image: Frame 1]
[image: Frame 19]
[image: Frame 20]

Comment: You can use [giantcowfilms](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to share your file, you need to copy the link to your question for that, as it's only mean for questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Checked out the file and found the culprit : Cartman is the bugger.

Aside from some wrong normals, the biggest problem is overlapping geometry.

Very heavy/bad for simulations that base on calculations using the geometry data of an object.

Suggestions to fix the problem:

1. Retopologize the object, reducing the vertex count and at the same time leads to not only a cleaner mesh, but a faster simulation.
2. Fixing the geometry of the object to have no overlapping parts anymore. If possible reduction of vertices wherever possible.

While both will take time, i'd go with the first one, as it would be training, and in a way easier, as you work from outside and around. While the latter would take longer i believe alone due to the very tight geometry in the leg/feet (bottom) part.

Without cleaning the the object, i don't think you should try getting the soft-body simulation to work, as all the fine tuning to get the object react as should won't compensate for the underlying problem.

There is a 3rd option, in case you just want the figure to fall in the glass.
No deformation like soft-body possible, but bouncing would work.
Rigid Body Simulation, making the figure an active object and both glass objects passive (important to set all objects to "Mesh" shape), will at least give you the experience of an Erik Cartman falling in a glass-jar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll to go for the first option of retopologizing the object as I'd like to get some practice. I'm learning how to retopologize as of right now and will come back to you when I'm done.

Comment: Nice, always good to improve by taking the challenge. Also once the object is clean and has no overlapping parts anymore the simulation should become a fun part.

Answer (score -1):

Xylvier already said some useful things, but what actually will fix this without any of those mentioned steps is increasing the max step size (of the solver). I set it to 10000, and behold:

[image]

This disappearing often happens if you have a softbody with many vertices colliding with something. I don't know why it already happens at frame 20 here, since there's no collision object nearby yet, but in those cases it's almost always fixable by increasing the max solver steps. 10000 is more than enough, but I didn't want to try to get the lowest value that's still working.

Obviously it's going to slow down the calculation, so you really might wanna reduce the vertex amount before doing the simulation anyway.

Comment: Brute-forcing around the main issue of having a bad topology/mesh used with the simulation is not helping much. It may be possible to get past the 20th frame, but the issue would still be there, while also slower, later then after the figure may have fallen further there will be more problems that won't be solved by increasing the solver steps again. So I'd suggest as in my answer to fix the root of the issue for the simulation, the bad geometry/mesh of the figure, which in turn not only speeds up the solver with less steps, but also results in a clean simulation.